# AppleScriptを利用してサウンド出力をヘッドフォンに切り替えたい。

Tags: applescript

サウンド出力をヘッドホンに切り替えるキーボードショートカットを設定しようと思ったのですが、標準でそのようなものが見当たりませんでしたのでAppleScriptを利用してできないか挑戦してみました。

しかしAppleScriptの構文がまったく理解できず、使えるようになるまでには少々時間がかかる印象を受けました。

YosemiteからJavascriptも利用可能になっているようなのでJavascriptでも構いませんので、サウンド出力をヘッドホンに切り替える簡単なスクリプトを教えていただけないでしょうか。

できれば、もう一度同じスクリプトを実行すると、ヘッドホンとライン出力のトグルができると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

切り替えに少し時間がかかってしまうのがネックですが、ヘッドフォン⇔ライン出力の切り替えを行うスクリプトです。

```
set output1 to "ヘッドフォン"
set output2 to "ライン出力"

tell application "System Preferences"
    launch
    activate

    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
    reveal (first anchor of current pane whose name is "output")

    tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
        set theTable to table 1 of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of window 1

        if (selected of row 1 of theTable whose value of text field 1 is output1) then
            select (row 1 of theTable whose value of text field 1 is output2)
        else if (selected of row 1 of theTable whose value of text field 1 is output2) then
            select (row 1 of theTable whose value of text field 1 is output1)
        end if
    end tell
end tell

quit application "System Preferences"
```

Comment: 素晴らしいです！！ありがとうございましたm(_ _)m